# Redirect React page to SAML login using Express backend with Passport

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, saml

I currently have a functional application in Express, but I am moving to React, thus express should act as an API now. Currently I am moving the login page but I am having a problem I do not know how to solve. For the login I have the following considerations:

- Using Passport to authenticate users
- Using SAML (SSO) to authenticate them
- To be able to authenticate through SSO, the user is redirected to the SSO page and then redirected back to the express app.

This login works with express because I can redirect through different pages. But I am unable to do this with react because I can't find a way to redirect to the SSO login page (redirecting back is done automatically by the SSO site).

**This is my current saml login**

```
router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('saml', {
      successRedirect: '/', // SUCCESS: Go to home page
      failureRedirect: 'login', // FAIL: Go to /user/login
    })
);
```

**This is the form where a user should login**

```
export class Login extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(){
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/auth/login",
          {method : 'POST'})
          .then(response => alert(response));
}


render(){
    return (
        <div className="flex h-screen">
            <div className="container m-auto max-w-md w-full space-y-8">
                <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
                   Sign in to your account
                 </h2>
                <form className="space-y-6 p-8" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="loginForm">
                    <div>
                       <button type="submit">
                         <span className="absolute left-0 inset-y-0 flex items-center pl-3">
                         Sign in
                       </button>
                     </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

As you can see, when a user presses the button, the submit handler is called, where I can do a post request, but I don't know how to continue with the authentication.

I have tried to add a `action="http://localhost:3000/auth/login" method="post"` to the form. This works, it successfully redirects to the SSO login page but there there are 2 problems here.

1. The redirect back does not work because it is a post request (it contains user information)
2. The redirect should be done to the express server, since it is the one that saves the cookies, passport, authentication data and it must complete the redirect.
3. I am not sure this would work with a real domain, outside local host.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, to authenticate I created a public subdomain `auth.domain.com` and launched a window popup to the authentication page, once the page is closed authentication should have been completed.

```
const authLoginURL = 'http://auth.domain.com/login';
const loginWindow = window.open(
                    authLoginURL,
                    "_blank"
            );
const timer = setInterval(() => {
            if(loginWindow.closed) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                this.props.callback();
            }
        }, 1000);
```